# Can rust save the compiler's optimization record?

Tags: rust, llvm, inline, compiler-optimization, rust-cargo

In C, I can output compiler optimization information using the following command:

```
clang -O2 main.c -o main -fsave-optimization-record
```

Does rust also have such options to output optimization information, such as function inline, parameter optimization, etc.
I tried the following command and it failed,

```
cargo rustc -- -C llvm-args=-fsave-optimization-record
```

The error information is as follows:

rustc -Cllvm-args="..." with: Unknown command line argument '-fsave-optimization-record'.  Try: 'rustc -Cllvm-args="..." with --help'

Comment: In *gcc.* This is not a general C language feature. Why you think a specific C compiler's option should apply to an arbitrary Rust implementation is a  mystery.

Comment: @user207421: Nobody mentioned GCC here.  The question makes sense because `clang` and `rustc` both use the same LLVM optimizing back-end.  You're correct that's not a general feature of all C compilers.  `-fsave-optimization-record` is an option GCC supports as well as clang, though, so perhaps clang only supports it for compat with GCC, and maybe has a different name for it that more closely matches LLVM's internal naming.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`remark`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#remark) and [`debuginfo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#debuginfo) codegen options.

```bash
> rustc main.rs -C remark=all -g
```

Note that `-g` is an alias for `-C debuginfo=2`. This option will enable remark to have the accurate source location.

Quoting from the documentation:

> **remark**
>
> This flag lets you print remarks for optimization passes.
> The list of passes should be separated by spaces.
> `all` will remark on every pass.
>
> **debuginfo**
>
> This flag controls the generation of debug information. It takes one
> of the following values:
>
> - `0` or `none`: no debug info at all (the default).
> - `line-directives-only`: line info directives only. For the nvptx*    targets this enables profiling. For other use cases, `line-tables-only`
>   is the better, more compatible choice.
> - `line-tables-only`: line tables only. Generates the minimal amount of    debug info for backtraces with filename/line number info, but not
>   anything else, i.e. no variable or function parameter info.
> - `1` or `limited`: debug info without type or variable-level information.
> - `2` or `full`: full debug info.

The output from this option won't be that readable. An alternative would be to consider using [`cargo-remark`](https://github.com/kobzol/cargo-remark).

See also:

- [Inspecting rustc LLVM optimization remarks using cargo-remark](https://kobzol.github.io/rust/cargo/2023/08/12/rust-llvm-optimization-remarks.html)